# EclipseLink - @ReadTransformer

Tags: eclipselink

I have this code:

```
@Column(name = "foo")
@ReadTransformer(transformerClass=transformer.class)
private Date foo;

public static class transformer implements AttributeTransformer {

    @Override
    public void initialize(AbstractTransformationMapping atm) {

}

    @Override
    public Object buildAttributeValue(Record record, Object o, Session sn) {

    }

}
```

My question is, how do I get the value to transform (from column foo) inside of buildAttributeVaule? It is not inside the record array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need one or more @WriteTransformer to write the fields you want selected (and thus get them selected), @Column is not used with a transformation mapping.

However, if you just have a single column, then just use a converter instead, @Convert,

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Mapping/Basic_Mappings/Default_Conversions_and_Converters

Answer (score 0):

First check that the SQL generated is reading in the "foo" column by turning on logging.  If it is, then check that the database is returning "foo" and not "FOO" - java is case sensitive on string looksups.  It could be that "FOO" is in the record instead of "foo".

Comment: Thanks for this, it appears to not be asking for the field in the select query it generates. I think it's because I do not specify a Temporal annotation for the date field. When I do, I receive an error (some dates in the database are invalid, thus why i'm using a transformer). It looks like I was mistaken to use transformer this way? Is there a solution which doesn't involve storing the invalid date in another (read-only) field (e.g. a string) for conversion? e.g. transform the value before it is validated?